# Remove space above and below single categorical y-axis in ggplot geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I would like to plot a series of small rectangular boxes, labelled with either 'R' or 'L', and filled according to that value. I'm able to produce this, but I want to remove all the space above and below the single y categorical axis value, to produce a short (y direction), but long (x direction) plot.

data:

```
dat = c("R", "R", "R", "L", "R", "R")
```

Attempt with ggplot2

```r
ggplot(NULL, aes(x=1:length(dat), y=factor(1), fill=dat, color=dat, label=dat)) +
  geom_point(shape=22, size=12) + 
  geom_text(color="black") + 
  labs(x="", y="")+
  scale_y_discrete(limits=factor(1))+
  theme(
    legend.position="none",axis.text = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  )
```

How do I remove the space above and below the single row of nicely labelled and filled boxes? I don't want to save the plot to a file, and change height/width etc, as it effects the aspect ratio of the individual boxes.

Edited: I figured out how to render this, basically the way I wanted, within a shiny app (see example below).  Thanks to @phalteman for prompting me to think more clearly about this.

Comment: I'm confused by your question - how the plot looks (without saving a plot to a file) is driven by the shape of your plot viewer. Are you in RStudio? By reshaping that plot window, I get a wide and short plot without any effect on the boxes. Can you be a bit more specific about where you envision your plot showing up in the format you describe?

Comment: you are right. i wasnt clear, and maybe the question isn't well conceived. I wanted to place this within a shiny app, but i think I've been a bit naive about the various options i have to size the rendered plot

Comment: Ok that’s making more sense. Can you edit your question to provide the additional context and an example of what you’ve tried in a (very simple) shiny app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within shiny app, the height of the rendered plot can be set to quite narrow range (below see example with 50px), without too much negative impact on the aspect ratio of the.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

generate_rnd_seq <- function(res_length) {
  factor(rbinom(res_length, 1, 0.3), level=c(0,1), labels=c("R","L"))
}

get_plot <- function(res_length) {

  dat = generate_rnd_seq(res_length)
  
  return(
    ggplot(NULL, aes(x=1:length(dat), y=factor(1), fill=dat, color=dat, label=dat)) +
    geom_point(shape=22, size=12) + 
    geom_text(color="black") + 
    labs(x="", y="")+
    scale_y_discrete(limits=factor(1))+
    theme(
      legend.position="none",axis.text = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank()
    )
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(numericInput("res_length", "Length of output", value=10, min=2, max=100, step=2)),
    mainPanel(
      shiny::plotOutput("boxes",height="50px"),
      HTML("This is some text below the plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$boxes <- shiny::renderPlot(get_plot(input$res_length))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer to this. Your solution is a good one for the problem you had, so accepting the answer signals to others that you have a solution.